# Как правильно хранить данные в формате "МАССИВ" в SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Как правильно или как обычно хранят данные в формате "МАССИВ" в SQL ? 
Массив типа String

Comment: Смотря какой массив и как его использовать, недостаточно подробностей.

Comment: вы будете обрабатывать значении массива в БД. или это просто временное хранение? Если просто временно хранить и при чтении будете читать в массив в вашем языке, тогда храните в виде json'а

Comment: С обработкой значения массива в БД и без тоже.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Массив в SQL чаще всего стоит хранить с отдельной таблице, по одному элементу массива в каждой строке, связанной с основной таблицей внешним ключом.

Т.е. если основная сущность лежит в таблицe SomeTable c PK SomeTableID, то массив можно положить в SomeTableArray вида:

```
ArrayValueID | SomeTableID (FK) | Value
           1 |                1 | string1
           2 |                1 | string2
           3 |                2 | string3
           4 |                2 | string4
```

Это добавит лишний запрос на чтение, но зато у вас будет нормально работать поиск. И намного проще будет проводить добавление новых элемента в массив.

Все другие варианты - хранение в виде строки (json/xml/csv) - вынудят вас при каждом поиске, например, string2, выбирать вообще все значения из базы в память и как-то их там парсить. Полноценно работать с ними на уровне БД не получится.

Comment: PashaPash Такую модель наблюдал на сервере л2,в таблице для хранения id друзей. Но у меня вопрос еще тогда возник. Допустим у нас 500 000 000 записей в этой таблице, и из них нам нужно выбрать только 2 записи , долго ли будет длиться в таком случае перебор всех записей в таблице?

Comment: @semiromid это зависит от наличия индексов. Поиск по индексу работает быстро - практически мгновенно.

Comment: PashaPash Тогда придется делать уникальные индексы для каждой записи в первой таблице (например :где хранятся пользователи а не их друзья)?   И этот ключь не подойдет тогда - INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT

Comment: Хотел бы заметить, если массив в виде строки сохранять в виде отсортированного массива, то поиск не быстрее, чем поиск по индексу в БД(использую бинарный поиск). Прочитал строку из БД, сделал поиск по сортированному массиву. Добавление нового элемента - тоже никаких проблем с этим нет, если написать удобно код для работы с БД. То есть в случаи сохранения в строке всю работу с работой с массивом мы берем на себя, а БД используем как хранилище. Все зависит от целей и задачей, в первую очередь, от размера массива. Если размер массива небольшой, то создавать отдельную таблицу считаю излишне.

Comment: Вот как пишут - Без индекса будет выполнен полный просмотр (сканирование) всех строк таблицы, что может оказать значительное влияние на производительность.   Кстати, массив может быть размером до 1000 ячеек.

Comment: @semiromid ну так создайте индекс, в чем проблема. не совсем понял что значит "уникальные индексы для каждой записи в первой таблице" - индексы работают не так. Создаете неуникальный индекс по UserID в таблице друзей - и он работает для поиска сразу по всем пользователям.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov Причем тут размер массива? Проблема не размере, а в том, что для поиска вам надо будет вычитать все массивы (все строки). Как, например, должен работать поиск "все строки, у которых в массиве есть 3" в вашема случае? Вычитать из базы **все** строки. Распарсить **все** массивы. Поискать в **каждом** массиве. Как вы себе это представляете для миллионов записей? А индекс в БД - это прошитое B-Tree. в нем такой поиск займет O(log n)

Comment: @semiromid разберитесь что такое индексы и как они работают. они не создаются для строк или для конкретных значений. Они создаются сразу для всей колонки. И позволяют быстро (очень быстро) искать по значению или по диапазону. Т.е. индекс по (UserID) позволяет быстро выбрать все записи для одного пользователя. Индекс по (UserID, FriendID) позволяет быстро определить, является ли конкретный пользователь другом другого. И индексы и ключи надо подбирать под конкретную структуру данных и под конкретные запросы.

Comment: А можно пример? А то я читаю про индексыhttp://habrahabr.ru/post/247373/ , и чего то никак не могу понять как они работают. Я с B-Tree никогда не работал.

Comment: @PashaPash, я с вами абсолютно согласен, но я еще раз повторю, смотря для каких целей нужно использовать сохранение массива. Если нужно прочитать запрос типа "все строки, у которых в массиве есть 3", то да, согласен, это будет беда, сохраняя массив в виде строки...

Comment: @PashaPash, Если же нас интересует какой-то один объект, и у него нужно проверить, а содержит ли он свойство с кодом 3(список свойств объекта - это целочисленный массив, массив храниться в виде строки), то тогда достаточно прочитать одну строку и выполнить бинарный поиск - и нет проблем... То есть дочернюю таблицу создавать необязательно, иногда(этих иногда бывает немало в моем случаи), нет необходимости создавать отдельную таблицу. Достаточно хранить в строке.
А про память я к тому, что для поиска придется всю строку загнать в память.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov да, если с массивом не нужно работать как с массивом на уровне базы - то хранить его можно как угодно.

Comment: @semiromid попробуйте вбить в таблицу много данных, и поискать по какому-нибудь полю. потом создать по нему индекс, и поискать по нему еще раз. сравнить планы выполнения (в mysql это делается через EXPLAIN) и посмотреть как именно сервер выполняет запросы с индексами и без.

Comment: PashaPash - записей почти  500 000.  Без индексов - SELECT id_use FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE position5='-90'  Время выполнения без индексов на поиски 3-х записей разбросанных в разных участках - почти мгновенно или мгновенно, EXPLAIN показал что перебираю все записи.    С ИНДЕКСАМИ - SELECT id_use FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE position5='-90' Время выполнение такое же, по очищением . EXPLAIN показал что перебрал только 3 записи. ВЫВОД: Странно конечно, может быть если будет 500 000 000 записей, тогда будет видна разница в скорости перебора, но пока её не видно

Comment: @semiromid хорошая девелоперская машина, небольшая база - целиком влазит в память. естественно, не будет разницы - перебрать пару мегабайт данных в памяти. на живой системе обычно все не так хорошо :) +, на некоторых вариантах SQL (Ms SQL точно, не уверен насчет My SQL) - перебор всех записей будет ждать всех блокировок на этих записях.

Comment: Как быть если массив используется в нескольких таблицах ? вводит еще один/несколько внешний ключ (FK) или делать отдельные дополнительные таблицы состоящие исключительно из внешний связывающих ключей (ключ на элемент из таблицы-массива и ключ на строку во внешней таблице где массив используется) ?

Answer (score 2):

Один из вариантов, массив хранить в виде строки , добавляя символ-разделитель между каждым элементом массива.
Например, массива из трех элементов

```
2 3 5
```

хранить в виде

```
2&3&5
```

При записи, мы сращиваем(splice) массив в одну строку и записываем ее в БД, при чтении мы читаем строку и делим строку на массив по разделителю(split).

Comment: Это только в том случае, если не будет поиска по массиву.

Comment: А как сделать если будет поиск по массиву? Вообще массив будет постоянно меняться  по размеру из-за данных.

Comment: в этом случаи, читаем данные из БД, получаем массив, и проводим любые модификации с ним, в том числе и поиск.